# Hashicorp vault Curl command for encryption more than 1 value at a time

Tags: curl, encryption, hashicorp-vault, bulk-load

curl command below will run for 1 value.. but unable to pass more than 1 values (or bulk input) for that..

curl --header 'X-Vault-Token:xxxx.....' --request POST --data '{"plaintext":"bWFzb29kQHhlcmFnby5jb20="}' http://localhost:8200/v1/transit/encrypt/

can some one help me with syntax to pass bulk input to vault hence from 1 curl command I can make multiple encryption and save time of encryption..

or is there any Prerequisite for it to use bulk input...

as of now I am using below list in curl command

[
  {
    "plaintext": "abcd1234",
  },
  {
    "plaintext": "efgh5678"
  }
]

please help me If u can

Comment: As documented: [the list goes into a batch_input property](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/transit#batch_input).